# Can not open Visio file on SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, office, visio

When I try to open a visio file in SharePoint I get this error:

> Sorry, we couldn't open your file using this feature. Visio Web Access
> is not available on this site

SharePoint version is 2019.
Already installed office online.
I installed Visio graph service on SharePoint server. After this error I reinstalled the service but nothing changed. Other office formats work fine and just Visio has this problem.

I'll be thankful if you share your experience with me to solve this issue.

Comment: Ensure SharePoint Server Enterprise Site features and SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection features have been activated.